# SFP not working on new switch

Tags: cisco, fiber, sfp

Switch: Cisco 2960G 24x 1G ports and 4x 10G SFP

SFP fiber module: 10Gtek AXS13-192-10

NIC: Solarflare SFN7122F

I got a new to me switch, after resetting to factory defaults I got it all configured for a very basic setup to just work off the serial console connection. I got my router plugged in and any of the 24 RJ45 ports work to connect any computer.

When I first tried to plug in the SFP module I got errors saying it wasn't an official module and the port was disabled.

So I got in puTTY and did the

```
no errdisable detect cause gbic-invalid

service unsupported-transceiver
```

Now it doesn't pop up with disabled errors but it doesn't seem to recognize the port as being plugged into my computer.
How do I get it to work? There are a lot of pages of people saying these SFP modules work so I just need to figure out how to make it so.

[image: ports connected]

Comment: Those are SFP (1G) ports, not SFP+ (10G).

Comment: How about this one? You think its any good?  https://unixsurplus.com/cisco-nexus-switch-n7k-m224xp-23l/       or you know any cheap models that have 10g

Comment: Sorry, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Comment: You do realize that's a BLADE for a CHASSIS? (your inability to do research is not our problem.)

Comment: My bad I posted the wrong link, but that's not allowed anyway it seems.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Switch: Cisco 2960G 24x 1G ports and 4x 10G SFP

SFP ports are 1G. 10G ports should be marked **SFP+**.

Running a 10G SFP+ module in an SFP slot is generally only possible when the module is explicitly marked 1G compatible and if the switch doesn't mind - most do.

```
no errdisable detect cause gbic-invalid
service unsupported-transceiver
```

These commands disable the rejection of non-Cisco transceivers (enable generic MSA) but cannot make incompatible modules work magically.

Also, you need to make sure that the NIC accepts its SFP+ module as well.

Both transceivers need to be using the same Ethernet variant (both 10GBASE-LR or both 10GBASE-SR). Your photo shows a multi-mode patch (looks somewhat orange) connected to the AXS13-192-10 transceiver which uses 10GBASE-LR over single-mode fiber (yellow). MMF might work for short range but will fail for longer ranges or when combined with SMF.

Comment: Thanks for that it seems I thought I saw SFP+ when I bought it but I guess not. Also perhaps your screen needs the color adjustment, that cable that's plugged into the SFP port is yellow. All my ports are single mode and I have only yellow single mode cables. I did buy a 1m orange one before I knew the difference in single and multi so I'm returning that but everything else is all single mode.